# facebook connect api static url

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

Is there a way to use the facebook connect api in a static way?

When we use the facebook php sdk the link or button to login to facebook is something like https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth..................

what I want is to eliminate the include of the php sdk on every page, because it will cause some extra processing and server load in peak times.

I want to make a session check to know if the user is logged in, by checking for exemple if his facebook user id and name are stored in the session, then if not, display a static login button. then after login with facebook he gets to facebook-login.php which will include the facebook php sdk and process his data and store them in the session, so that he remains logged without including the php sdk in each page.

the url structure that I get with $facebook->getLoginUrl() is:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={MY_APP_KEY}&scope={PERMISSIONS}&redirect_uri={MY_SITE/facebook-login.php}&state={A_32_CHAR_CODE_LIKE_MD5_MAYBE}

The final question is: WHAT WOULD BE THE URL IN THE LOGIN BUTTON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just load the sdk and do something like:

```
echo '<a href="' . $facebook->getLoginUrl( array('next'=>'http://mysite.com', 'req_perms' => 'email,read_stream,publish_stream')) . '">Connect to Facebook</a>';
```

that url will always be valid for a logged out user

Comment: sorry you didn't understand my question, I want to include the facebook php sdk ONLY in facebook-login.php which is the redirect_uri that I made. I will edit my question for further details.

Comment: no, I was just telling you how to dynamically build the static link so you could copy and paste it;) after you've loaded the sdk and echoed that, just copy the link href and then turn off the include:)

Comment: ok take a look at my edit and tell me if these values and generally that url would be always the same or it changes? (mainly the "state" param as the others are pre-defined by me)

Comment: yup, there are no values there that will ever change, that is your static login url

Comment: I just viewed the page with IE and everything was the same as in FF except the "state" param which had a diiferent value

Comment: I think this is a cross-site request forgery check: 

self::errorLog('CSRF state token does not match one provided.');
 it's in facebook-base.php

Comment: It' changing from user agent to another and with FF when I cleared all coockies it has changed and when I removed it it worked, can you confirm that?

Comment: yup, check out [the facebook developers authentication guide](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) for more info

Answer (score 0):

This is a good question. First, a user is logged into you app means that **you have a valid access token for the user**.

And there is no way to be sure that an access token is valid before making an API call with this access token. So if you want to make sure the user is still logged in on each page, you have to make an API call to Facebook on each of them. Kind of heavy, but there is no other solution.

What you can do is assume that the access token you have is valid and check only once a while (when you really need to be sure the user is logged in).

You can have different scenario :

- you have **no Facebook data** about the user : the user is not logged in your app for sure.
- you can **read the user ID**, but you may not have an access token for this user : the user may not be logged in.
- you can read an **access token**, but it may not be valid (has expires or revoked by the user) : the user may not be logged in.
- you have a **valid access token** : the user is logged in for sure.

You can read the user ID and the access token in the session. The session array looks like that :

```
[fb_148195765253871_access_token] => 14819576525...
[fb_148195765253871_user_id] => 1536397056
```

The number in the keys of the array (here `148195765253871`) is your app ID.

So what you can do on each page is to check if those keys are set and if they are not, load the SDK and double-check (because the access can be store in some other places that the SDK is reading) :

```
if (isset($_SESSION['fb' . YOUR_APP_ID . 'access_token'])) {
    // assume to user is logged in
    // and keep going
} else {
    require "facebook.php";
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'  => YOUR_APP_ID,
        'secret' => YOUR_APP_SECRET,
    ));

    // Make an API call to be sure the user is logged in
    // ie : that you have a valid access token
    $user = $facebook->getUser(); // User ID
    if ($user) {
        try {
            $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            $user = null;
        }
    }

    if ($user) {
        // The user is logged in for sure
    } else {
        // The user is not logged in for sure
        // Make him log in
        echo '<a href="' . $facebook->getLoginUrl() . '">Login with Facebook</a>';
    }
}
```

Hope that helps !

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer does not really answer the question.

If you would like to isolate all the Facebook code necessary for generating the getLoginUrl function call into a separate file you can do this easily by using meta refresh.

So in your header point the link "Login With Facebook" to "facebook_login.php".  On this page include the necessary calls from the SDK for getLoginUrl and than add the following line of HTML.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=<?=$helper->getLoginUrl(array('email', 'user_friends'));?>">
```

I tested this out multiple times and it works.

FYI using Facebook SDK 4.0.